A tag for "How can I become familiar with the logic syntax used in Cryptography papers" question
This question tagged as encryption. encryption tag is not suitable tag for the question.  Which tag is suitable for such questions?  It seems we need a new tag for such questions.

The encryption tag is not suitable for the question, you are right.
For questions about the syntax we have the notation tag – I added it there. There is also the related tag terminology.
The question itself actually is not a really good fit on our site, I suppose – it borders on "please recommend me a book", and such questions are not really constructive. I'm a bit on doubt on what to do with the question, whether it could be reworded or should be closed.
